# Swift: UIImage has twice the size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

When I draw a border around a UIImage with

```
    let opaque = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize.init(width: ((self.imageView?.image?.size.width)!+512), height: (self.imageView?.image?.size.height)!+512), opaque, scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.setFillColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
    context?.fill(CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: (context?.width)!, height: (context?.width)!))

    self.imageView?.image?.draw(at: CGPoint.init(x: 256, y: 256))

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

and print out its size, it is totally correct, as I set it: width and height each + 256.

However, when I save the image to library, it has twice its width and twice its height. I have no idea why. Also (and this is the part that annoys me the most), when I want to draw something on the image, also it seem to have twice the sizes...

Comment: You need to understand the difference between points and pixels.

Comment: Your UIImageView is 256x256. But check the UIImage size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Maddy, for bringing me on the right track!

The solution is: The ScaleFactor has to be 1:

```
let scale: CGFloat = 1
```

Comment: Only do this is you really do want the image to have a specific size in pixels versus an appropriate size in points.